# Drone Deploy Export to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, dronedeploy

Good afternoon, my apologies if this simple question/answer is in the DroneDeploy GitBooks but I am in the initial stages of developing a geoprocessing app for your platform and was wondering, what is the recommended way to auto-export either a processed orthomosaic or DSM from DroneDeploy to an Amazon S3 bucket? In the Exporter examples it seems like the default behavior is to generate a link then send that link via a defined email address - however is there a method to directly send it to Amazon? Is this the "webhook" function as outlined in the documentation?

webhook: {
url: 'http://www.url-to-ping-on-complete.com/any-params-here' // recieve the export document when its complete
}

Thank you,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

At high level here is how you can accomplish this.

1. When you use the dronedeploy embedded api to start your export you would pass the url to your server in the [webhook field](https://dronedeploy.gitbooks.io/dronedeploy-apps/content/exporter.html#orthomosaic-export).
2. When the export finishes dronedeploy will `POST` the the [export document](https://support.dronedeploy.com/v1.0/docs/data-api-access#section-parameters) to the webhook you specified.
3. On your server you will select the `exportDocument.download_path` and download the file.
4. Once the file is downloaded you can then upload it to aws.

Please note some of the exports can be rather large and it will take considerable time to download and upload the export. If another export happens before you've finished the last export your server might be blocked from accepting the next request. It might be a good idea to use a lambda service such as [firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) or [aws lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html).